# Navigate to a link using html session in R

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to navigate to a link on a website. All the links work except for one single link. Here are the results.

```
> mcsession<-html_session("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/tataconsultancyservices/balance-sheetVI/TCS#TCS")

> mcsession<-mcsession %>% follow_link("Previous Years »")
Error: No links have text 'Previous Years »'
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl(i, text, fixed = TRUE) : input string 316 is invalid UTF-8

> mcsession<-mcsession %>% follow_link("Balance Sheet")
Navigating to /financials/tataconsultancyservices/balance-sheetVI/TCS#TCS
Warning message:
In grepl(i, text, fixed = TRUE) : input string 316 is invalid UTF-8
```

Any idea why this happens so?

Comment: If you look at the page, you'll see that you are not targeting a normal link. In fact, clicking on 'Previous Years' does not load a new page, but instead returns a javascript function called `post_prevnext()`. As far as I know, `rvest` can't follow that link because it's not really a link to another page. I think that your best bet is to use `RSelenium` to navigate the page programmatically in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a normal link - it is javascript.  I don't know of a way of doing it with `rvest`, but you could use `RSelenium`, which basically automates a normal browser window.  It is slower than scraping directly, but you can automate just about anything that you can do by hand.  This works for me (using chrome on Windows 10)...

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/tataconsultancyservices/balance-sheetVI/TCS#TCS")

firstpage <- remDr$getPageSource() #you can use this to get the first table

#(1)
webElem1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'partial link text', value = "Previous Years")
webElem1$clickElement()

nextpage <- remDr$getPageSource() #you can use this to get the next page for previous years

#repeat from #(1) to go back another page etc 

remDr$closeall() #when you have finished.
```